# shakaijin or otona?

Tags: meaning, words

I have always used the word otona to signify adult. Recently, I have seen the word shakaijin. Is there a significant difference between the two words？ It seems like shakaijin is a member of society. Can I use both words interchangeably?

Comment: It would seem strange to routinely use "member of society" in place of "adult" in English. I would guess the same applies to Japanese.

Comment: @jkerian, there must be a meaning or situation that I am not familiar with.

Comment: That sounds like you're wondering about a particular use.  In that case it might be best to post that example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 大人 is "adult", someone who is mature enough. It typically refers to anyone over 18 or 20.
- 社会人 is someone who has started to work regularly. It's mainly used in business contexts. A 22-year old university student is usually not called a 社会人 yet. So 社会人 is somewhat closer to a (responsible) **businessperson**, although  社会人 also includes farmers, novelists and such.

See also: [What's the difference between 成人 and 大人?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2986/5010)